# How do I correctly describe this 4x4 square in my K-map?

Tags: karnaugh-map

I am trying to find a (SoP)-expression using the embedded K-map. I have a box of size 4x4 which is a permitted use however I am having a hard time understanding how I could implement it.

To me the 4x4 box represents that the output is always 1 independet on any of the variables. Then I'd like to use the 2x4 box to the right and produce:
1 OR (Qc AND !Qd), but this does not produce the correct result.

I can see several alternative ways to produce the correct result. My questions are specifically:

1. Why can't I use the 4x4 box, or perhaps, how do I represent it correctly?
2. How do I know when I can represent parts of the output as a 4x4 box?

Perhaps Im missing something more fundamental.
Thx in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The point of placing rectangles in a K-map is to eliminate variables from an expression. When the result of a rectangle is the same for the variable values `X` and `X'`, then the variable `X` is not needed and can be removed. You do this by extending an existing rectangle by doubling the size and eliminating exactly **one** variable, where every other variable stays the same. For the common/normal K-map with four variables this works with every such rectangle because in a way the columns/rows are labelled/positioned. See the following example:

[image: normal K-Map with four variables]

The rectangle has eliminated the variables `A` and `B`, one variable at a time when the size of the rectangle has been extended/doubled. This results in the function `F(A,B,C,D) = C'D'`. But check the following K-map of four variables:

[image: different K-Map with four variables]

Notice that the columns for the `D` variable has been changed (resulting in a different function overall). When you try to extend the red rectangle to catch the other two `1` values as well, you are eliminating **two** variables at the same time (`B` and `D`). As you cannot grow the rectangle anymore, you are left with two rectangles, resulting in the function `F(A,B,C,D) = BC'D' + B'C'D` (which can be simplified to `C' * (BD' + B'D)`).

The practice in placing rectangles in the K-map isn't just placing the biggest rectangle possible, but to eliminate variables in the right way. To answer your questions, you can always start with the smallest rectangle and extend/double its size to eliminate **one** variable. See the following example:

[image: K-map with six variables]

The green rectangle grows in these steps:

1. Start with `A'BC'D'E`
2. Eliminate the (only) variable `A` by growing "down", resulting in `BC'D'E`
3. Eliminate the (only) variable `D` by growing "right", resulting in `BC'E`.

But now, the rectangle cannot grow/double its size anymore because that would eliminate the variable `E`, but also somehow eliminate the variable `C`. You cannot eliminate the variable `E`, because you have `0` values to the left of the green rectangle and `1` values to the right of the green rectangle (all in the left half of the K-map, where you have the value `C'`). The only way to increase/grow the rectangle is to get the "don't care" values to eliminate the `B` variable (not shown here).

The overall function for this K-map would be `F(A,B,C,D,E) = C'E + DE' + CD'` (from three 2x4 rectangles).

Comment: Thxx a lot, great answer. It has become clearer to me now!

Comment: the mirror concept is not explained here

Comment: see https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/larger-5-6-variable-karnaugh-maps/